# basic keyboard handler in C

Tags: c, keyboard, operating-system

I am trying to develop a basic OS using assembly and C and I am kind of stuck in developing the keyboard driver.
I use the following two functions to get a line from the user through the keyboard

```
char getchar() {
    char c;
    int i;

    while(char_count == 0);

    c = buffer[0];

    for(i=0 ; i<KEYBOARD_BUFFER_SIZE ; i++) {
    buffer[i] = buffer[i+1];
    }

    char_count--;
    push_index--;

    return c;
}

char* getline(unsigned char password_mode) {
    char* line;
    char c = 0x00;
    int index = 0;

    while(c != '\n') {

        if(c) {
            if(!password_mode)
                printch(c);
            else
                printch('*');

            if(c == '\b')
                index--;
            else
                line[index++] = c;
    }

            c = getchar();
    }

    line[index] = '\0';

    return line;
}
```

However, when I try to get the username and the password from the user, I ask him to enter the username first and then enter the password, the problem is that the password overwrites the username which leads to incorrect data. How can the password be written over the username ? and does that mean that the `char* arr` allocated in `getline()` has the same address each time the function is accessed ? 
thanks for you help

Comment: Make a copy of the buffer? (You have a `malloc` or something implemented, right?

Comment: I don't think I can use `malloc`
and by the way I am compiling in the `-ffreestanding` mode

Comment: I know you can't use stock `malloc`; I've experimented with systems programming in the past. I was wondering if you'd *implemented* a `malloc` or `kmalloc` or something. (You should probably worry about that before worrying about passwords.)

Comment: No, I didn't implement `malloc` myself. This is my first experience in developing operating systems.

Comment: There are some good tutorials available on the internet. I used to swear by [this one](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/1.-Environment%20setup.html), which among other things went over `malloc` (but the site seems to be down at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is you're not allocating any memory to read your input into. `char* line;` declares line as a pointer to char pointing to a random bit of memory. So dereferencing line via `line[index++] = c` takes you straight into undefined behaviour - you're writing to memory that you don't own.  It's pretty much pure fluke that subsequent calls to getline are hitting the same bit of memory and overwriting what went before.

So you need to change getline to actually read into memory you own.

One option is to change the declaration of line to a static char array; something like `static char line[100];`.  This would give you some actual memory to work with. However this guarantees that each call to getline will definitely write to the same area of memory. It would then be up to the caller to copy the input somewhere else if it needs to be preserved beyond the next call to getline.

Another option would be to change getline to accept a buffer from the caller, something like `getline(unsigned char password_mode, char *line, size_t line_size)`. That way you can pass different arrays to each call.

Whichever option you choose you'd also want to make sure you're not in danger of overrunning the buffer inside getline by reading more characters than you have room for.